# I have an array of few repetitive elements, I want to find the index of the repetitive element which is closest to end of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++14, binary-search

I have an array of few repetitive elements, and I want to find the index of the repetitive element which is closest to end of the array.

```
#include<iostream>
uisng namespace std;
int main()
{
  int arr[15]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,10,11,12,13};   // 8 is repeating 3 times

// lets find the index of element 8 which is closest from the end

 int index;

for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
  {
    if(arr[i]==8)
     {
       index=i;break;
     }
  }      
      cout<<index;
return 0;
}
```

This was easy but if the array is very large, suppose if size of array was 10^6 then it could take up some time. I have been told one economic way is to use binary search! How can I use the binary search if there are multiple elements to find index of the repetitive element which is closest to the end, considering the repetitive element is given?

Comment: Did you try writing binary search? Think about how you would decide between recursing left and recursing right.

Comment: Is the assumption that repeated elements are consecutive? Any other constraints you didn't mention?

Comment: is the array sorted? and when you say 'find the index of the repetitive element which is closest to end of the array' - does it mean if there are multiple repeating elements - you have to find the one which comes last in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a binary search is the way to go. I would propose to look at [std::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound). Also mentioned in the references are examples how an implementation may look like:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
ForwardIt upper_bound(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    ForwardIt it;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first,last);

    while (count > 0) {
        it = first; 
        step = count / 2; 
        std::advance(it, step);
        if (!(value < *it)) {
            first = ++it;
            count -= step + 1;
        } else count = step;
    }
    return first;
}
```

Source also [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound).